# Replace a column starting from a certain row

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this example:

```py
rates_frame = rates_frame[['new_date', 'new_time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'tick_volume']]
rates_frame
rates_frame.head()
```

Which produces this output:

[image: Rates dataframe]

I want to replace values in column `open` starting from row 1 by values from column `close` starting from row 0.

Comment: Hi, SO aren't a coding workforce. We're here for help, but, can you try it and post some of your tests?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `shift` function in `pandas`. This shifts the values in the particular column by a specified number of periods

All you need is this

```
rates_frame['open_new'] = rates_frame['close'].shift(1)
```

**PS**: From the perspective of the share market, I don't think you should do this. It's not necessary that the opening price of today is equal to the closing price of the previous day. You can look into topics like gap-up opening, gap-down opening and unchanged.
Only in the latter case, what you are doing holds true.

Comment: Thanks you are right regrading the perspective.